# How to access and use database in Window Phone 7?

Tags: database, windows-phone-7

I am new to Window Phone 7 development and I want to create a simple database driven application. But I couldn't find a reference of `System.Data.Linq` or other dlls in my Windows Phone application. How can I do database operation, please give me easy solution.

Comment: You should probably use WCF Data Services or a similar technology; you should not connect directly to SQL Server from the phone.

Answer (score 1):

This is a topic too complex to fit in a single, short answer. What got me going (if your question is about *local* databases) is the official introduction on MSDN: [Local Database Overview for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202860%28v=VS.92%29.aspx). This might already give you all information you need, in any case it has all the keywords you need for doing further research.

Answer (score 0):

There are many sources of this information.  For starters, here is a link to the video in the MSDN How-To videos: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh336286

Here is a great link on delicio.us: Using SQL CE on WP7 Mango–Getting Started
http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2011/07/21/using-sql-ce-on-wp7-mango-getting-started.aspx

Here is a good one from Chris Koenig (MS Developer Evangelist): 
http://chriskoenig.net/2011/10/14/using-databases-with-mango

And here is one by Claudiu Farcas: 
http://claudiufarcas.blogspot.com/2011/10/windows-phone-mango-sql-ce-tips-and.html

These are some great resources to get you started.